# What to do with a wrong question

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, answers

I asked this question some time ago
[Getter and setter for unique_ptr object (dependency injection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011113/getter-and-setter-for-unique-ptr-object-dependency-injection)

As you see in the comments I had the right idea but the problem was somewhere else. The one and only answer wasn't as helpful as the demand for an SSCCE in the comments. Because in the end that led me to rebuild everything (which was - in fact - the solution).

So, there is no answer I'd like to accept. The solution had nothing to do with the original question. Should it be closed then? Still, the information given (about getters / setters) in the question I consider somewhat valueable for others.

How to go on?

Comment: If you;re still happy the question itself is good, and it's just the answer that isn't then there's nothing you need do. There is no requirement to have to accept an answer, just leave it and wait for a better answer, or if you find the answer yourself then add that to the post and accept your own answer.

Comment: @JonW Your comment could be an answer by itself!

Comment: How funny that now something similar happened to this very question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JonW pointed out in the comments

> If you;re still happy the question itself is good, and it's just the answer that isn't then there's nothing you need do. There is no requirement to have to accept an answer, just leave it and wait for a better answer, or if you find the answer yourself then add that to the post and accept your own answer.

And I think that's the way I will treat this.